# How to check GoogleCredential if it is expired

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0, credentials, access-token

I have initialized the GoogleCredential variable from saved-access-token and saved-refresh-token. But i don't know to check it expired or not ?

I know that GoogleCredential has a function getExpiresInSeconds. But if i initialize GoogleCredential from the saved-access-token and saved-refresh-token,the function getExpiresInSeconds will return null.

This case getExpiresInSeconds will not null

```
mResponse = mFlow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
mCredential =  new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).setJsonFactory(mJsonFactory).setTransport(mHttpTransport).build();
mCredential.setFromTokenResponse(mResponse);
mCredential.getExpiresInSeconds() // will return expired value in second
```

but in this case

```
String accessTokenSave = mPrefs.getString(GOOGLE_DRIVE_TOKEN, "NO KEY");
String accessRefreshTokenSave = mPrefs.getString(GOOGLE_DRIVE_REFRESH_TOKEN, "NO KEY");

mHttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
mJsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
mCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
.setJsonFactory(mJsonFactory)
.setTransport(mHttpTransport).build();

mCredential.setAccessToken(accessTokenSave);
mCredential.setRefreshToken(accessRefreshTokenSave);
mCredential.getExpiresInSeconds() // will return null value
```

So how can i check mCredential the case load it from accessTokenSave and accessRefreshTokenSave

Comment: I'm using this library its really sample. http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An access token expires in one hour while the refresh token will be valid until revoked by the user. However, you should never rely on these times and instead be prepared to catch an exception whenever credentials are no longer valid, and react accordingly.

Check the documentation for the description on the complete flow, together with sample code implementing it: https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials

Comment: This is not an acceptable response Claudio, specially if you're a Google Senior Developer Program Engineer -.-". I have the same problem even if i copied the code from the official documentation. I know that stackoverflow permit to open a temporary chat (but i don't knwo how). If you have no problems to disucs with, contact me (and i promise i'm posting the solution in the nearly future) or please, rewrite your response for @quantm and all interested users. Thank you so much ;-)